# MySQL Triggers, drop query inside trigger

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a trigger to not allow an update of a relation if a statement is true, and I am running into some trouble

```
CREATE TRIGGER noPriceLowerSpeed
BEFORE UPDATE
ON pc
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF(new.speed IS IN (SELECT speed FROM pc AS pc1) AND pc1.price < new.price) 
THEN DROP new
END IF;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT speed FROM pc AS pc1) AND pc1.price <
>   new.price)  THEN DROP new

I am trying to not allow a pc into my pc relation if it has a higher price than a pc with the same speed.

How might I write this trigger to just not allow the update?

Answer (score 0):

`IS` is superfluous. You should just use the following syntax:

```
new.speed IN( ... )
```

Also, I think you missed a `;` after `THEN DROP new`.

Comment: This helps some. But how might I modify my then statement to not allow the update to happen?

Comment: This still does not help. How do I tell MySQL to not allow a change iside a trigger if a condition is not met?

Comment: It doesn't seem as if there's an easy way of doing that. But you can try a workaround like this one: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,99214,99300#msg-99300.

Answer (score 0):

To make the statement fail, use the SIGNAL statement in the trigger, to raise an error.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html